# Reuse ChapterHead format to Chapter*

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I have defined a specific format for Head Chapter

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
{\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
    \Large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
    \par\nobreak
    %\vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
    \thispagestyle{empty}
}}
```

But when I use chapter*{} command it is not used. How can avoid that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. For starred chapters, there is the macro `\@makeschapterhead`, they are unnumbered and do not need a number style definition.

Comment: With `titlesec`, you *might* be able to define the chapterhead for both instances at once, but i do not like the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\chapter`'s title/heading is set with `\@makechapterhead` while `\chapter*`'s title/heading is set with `\@makeschapterhead`. So, in order to maintain the same flavour of content you've defined, copy the definition and remove the parts about setting the label `Chapter X`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
{\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
    \Large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
    \par\nobreak
    %\vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
    \thispagestyle{empty}
}}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
{\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    %\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    %\if@mainmatter
    %\Large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
    %\par\nobreak
    %%\vskip 20\p@
    %\fi
    %\fi
    %\interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
    \thispagestyle{empty}
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\chapter*{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```